# Expo debug remote JS causes unresponsiveness in UI

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo

I upgraded a react native project recently from expo SDK 36 to 38.  It compiles now, but anytime I click on "Debug Remote JS", it causes the UI to become slow and unresponsive, only occasionally picking up the on click events.  I created a bare bones project to duplicate it.  To verify, either run expo init from cli or here's a project `https://github.com/seniordevops/tab-application.git`.  Click the tabs without the debugger on, then turn on debug remote JS and watch the slow down.  Happens on both Mac and PC.  Any ideas on the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly due to the fact that the clock on your PC and mobile are not synchronized.

You either have to synchronize them or have the phone clock one second earlier than your PC/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason could be an upstream problem of react-native. Please check this expo-cli issue:

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2405

a maintainer reports:

> when you are debugging on your device, the javascript is being
> executed in your browser on your computer :(